# Pagination with data from Random Ordered Source

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, caching, pagination

**Situation**
I am working on a project (CodeIgniter - PHP MySQL) that sources data from an Ad_API and display those listings in my site. The API talks JSON with loads of data (~1kb) about each single entity. I show around 20 - 30 such entities per page so that's what i request the server (about ~20kb data). The server gives data in a random manner and data can **not** be requested back for single entity by supplying any identifier.

**Problem**
I, now have to show more results (200+) with pagination. If it were a MySQL db I was querying thing would be butter but here I cant.

**My Argument to Solutions**

- **jQuery Pagination :** Yes that is an option but again, i will have to load all 200 data entities on the user's browser at once then paginate them using jQuery

So does anyone have any better solution. Please read the situation carefully before answering because this scenario is very different from the ones we come across in daily life.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the API data in a MySQL table temporarily just for the pagination purpose?.

You may also be interested in MongoDB and store the JSON data in a MongoDB collection and paginate from it.

Comment: Lets see. We do these things 1)Fetch data from API & parse it. 2)Store them in database 3)Query DB - Get some data out. 4)Send it to user. . . I am not very sure but it looks like a bit time consuming apart from the point that I will end up with Gigabytes of data in my database in seconds and my site's core functionality will suffer.

Comment: Yes..Of course, you have to store it temporarily.This can be done easily with MySQL or MongoBD